# Concept of a Stream Device

Tags: computer-architecture, operating-systems, filesystems

In class, professor mentions that there are Stream and Storage devices. I mean to ask about Stream devices. I've also heard the terminology [character](https://linux-kernel-labs.github.io/refs/heads/master/labs/device_drivers.html) devices.

On a Linux VM, the corresponding terminal devices can be seen via the `proc` file system:

```
$ ls -l /proc/$$/fd
total 0
lrwx------ ... ... ... 0 -> /dev/tty1
lrwx------ ... ... ... 1 -> /dev/tty1
lrwx------ ... ... ... 10 -> /dev/tty1
lrwx------ ... ... ... 2 -> /dev/tty1
```

It seems that stdin, stdout, stderr all point to the same device, and `zsh` maintains fd `10` for access to the terminal.

I'm wondering specifically about how the terminal works and programs like shell interact with it, since it seems that programs like `cat` only receive input on `<Enter>` when reading stdin. Something curious I found is that you can also write to stdin much like stdout, so I am wondering how the offsets are maintained, since these devices do not have a valid [lseek](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/lseek.html).

Here is an example:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main () {
  write(STDIN_FILENO, "hello\n", 6);
  return 0;
}
```

My question is really: what is managing the data you type into your computer and you see on your screen, if it is not "Storage"? I am asking about the concept of a "Stream" device and the above are examples.